# AngularJS parsing expression in form tag fails

Tags: angularjs

Is there any reason why expression is not parsed inside a form tag ?

Outside scope and inside of a form, serviceUrl parses ok, but refuses to render inside form tag (just renders literally `'%7B%7B%20serviceUrl%20%7D%7D'`).

```
{{ serviceUrl }}

<form name="form" action="{{ serviceUrl }}" target="target_frame" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {{ serviceUrl }}

</form>
```

Comment: maybe try `ng-attr-action` attribute

Comment: For reference: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings

Comment: Thanks, but that also gives me all sorts of interpolation errors and just parses "serviceUrl"

Comment: Error: [$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$interpolate/interr?p0=myserviceurlhere

Comment: Clicking on error gives me this explanation Error: $sce:insecurl
Processing of a Resource from Untrusted Source Blocked

Comment: So you're probably pointing to an external service. Use `$sce.trustAsUrl` method, see if it helps (although I'm not too sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was security issue in newer Angular version (1.2.7), indeed as gustavohenke suggested it needed using **ng-attr-action = "{{ serviceUrl }}"**

and in controller

```
$scope.serviceUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://yoururl");
```